# This warning in clang and gcc doesn't seem to be correct

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

I believe the example below in page 66 of Bjarne Stroutrup's new book, TCPL 4th edition, has a minor error, as the `class Vector_container` doesn't have an `std::initializer_list` constructor. The error message [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87350171f02c5b97) confirms this.

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector{
    double* elem;
    int sz;
public:
    Vector(int s):elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { for(int i = 0; i != sz; ++i) elem[i]= 0; }
    Vector(std::initializer_list<double> lst): elem{new double[lst.size()]}, sz(lst.size()) { std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), elem); }
    ~Vector() { delete[] elem; }
    double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }
    int size() const { return sz; }
};

class Container{
public:
    virtual double& operator[](int i) = 0;
    virtual int size() const = 0;
    virtual ~Container() {}
};

class Vector_container:public Container{
    Vector v;
public:
    Vector_container(int s): v{s}{}
    ~Vector_container() {}
    double& operator[](int i) { return v[i]; }
    int size() const {return v.size(); }
};

void use(Container& c)
{
    const int sz = c.size();
    for(int i = 0; i != sz; i++) std::cout << c[i] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Vector_container vc{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    use(vc);
}
```

But the warning emitted for the expression `v{s}` in the member-initializer list for the `Vector_container(int)` constructor surprised me, as it says: `warning: narrowing conversion of 's' from 'int' to 'double' inside { }`, which doesn't seem to be correct, as there's no narrowing in this case.

Also, if you change the expression `Vector_container vc{10, ..., 1};` in `main()` to `Vector_container vc{10};` the error message disappears, as expected, but the warning continues to show off. Nonetheless the `std::initializer-list` constructor for the `Vector` class is chosen by the compiler, and I presume this to be correct, according to 13.3.1.7/1 in the Standard.

Thus, I wonder **if there's any way to impose the invoking of the `Vector(int)` constructor, instead of the initializer-list ctor** in the `Vector` class, in this last example with `Vector_container vc{10};`.

Comment: Inside `Vector_container(int s)`, `s` is not a constant expression, so there's a narrowing conversion from `int` to `double`. clang++3.5 says it's an *error*, not just a warning.

Comment: *"Thus, I wonder if there's any way to impose the invoking of the `Vector(int)` constructor,"* Don't use list-initialization in `Vector_container(int s)`? --> `Vector_container(int s): v(s){}`

Comment: @dyp `Don't use list-initialization in Vector_container(int s)?` But what if you want to keep this constructor in the class?

Comment: I'm not sure which constructor you're referring to.

Comment: @dyp What I'm saying is: how to enforce the Vector(int) constructor maintaining the initializer-list constructor in the Vector class?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you mean :( Do you want to keep this constructor: `Vector_container(int s): v{s}{}` but change something in the `Vector` class so that in `Vector_container(int s): v{s}{}`, the initializer-list ctor of `Vector` will not be called, but the `int` ctor instead?

Comment: Hmm in my version of the book it *does* say `Vector_container(int s): v(s) { }` on page 66. I have the First Printing, July 2013.

Comment: @dyp That's the same in the fourth edition. Probably, this was my error when I typed the code in Coliru. But this does not invalidate my observation about the error in the TCPL book.

Comment: That's true, and it doesn't appear in the [list of errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct about the overload resolution: Inside

```
Vector_container(int s): v{s}{}
```

the initialization `v{s}` selects the following constructor:

```
Vector(std::initializer_list<double> lst)
```

as per [over.match.list]/1.

When the `std::initializer_list<double>` is created from `{s}`, where `s` is of type `int`, there is a narrowing conversion from `int` to `double` (n3485) [dcl.init.list]/7

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - [...]
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will
>     produce the original value when converted back to the original type, or
> - [...]

Note that `s` here is not a constant expression any more (being a parameter). Narrowing conversions may not appear in the construction of an `std::initializer_list` object, [dcl.init.list]/5

> If a narrowing conversion
>   is required to initialize any of the elements, the program is ill-formed.

So that warning should be an error (or it's an extension).

---

> Thus, I wonder if there's any way to impose the invoking of the `Vector(int)` constructor, instead of the initializer-list ctor in the `Vector` class.

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly (see comments to OP), but not using list-init here solves the problem:

```
Vector_container(int s): v(s) {}  // initializer-list ctor not viable
```

Comment: `Vector_container(int s): v(s) {}` That's exactly what I was looking for. This way you enforce the Vector(int) constructor to be called. Good answer. Tks.

Comment: Another pitfall of "uniform initialization". Maybe if it wouldn't include `std::initializer_list`-initialization, it would be less complicated and less surprising...

Comment: `When the std::initializer_list<double> is created from {s}, where s is of type int, there is a narrowing conversion from int to double (n3485) [dcl.init.list]/7` But what is the real problem with this so called "narrowing" conversion?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil You mean, why have they made that ill-formed? That's a good question, if all values of `int` can be represented in the floating point type. It must have something to do with the floating point, as similar conversions between integers are allowed.